# Create a Stored Procedure for AES Encryption in MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, encryption, aes

I have an SQL Server 2008 table with a structure similar to the following:

```
ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
Name nvarchar(100)
LongText ntext
```

What I am trying to achieve is simple. Before inserting data inside this table, I want to encrypt the LongText using AES_192 algorithm. I am using the following SP to encrypt data:

```
create proc sp_Encrypt_LongText
@rawText ntext = null,
@encryptedText nvarchar(max) output
as
begin
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY Encryption_Symmetric_Key
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Encryption_Certificate WITH PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
set @encryptedText = ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID(N'Encryption_Symmetric_Key'), cast(@rawText as nvarchar(max)))
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY Encryption_Symmetric_Key    
end
```

and for decryption, I have created the following SP:

```
alter proc sp_Decrypt_LongText
@encryptedText ntext = null,
@decryptedText varchar(max) output
as
begin
    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY Encryption_Symmetric_Key
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Encryption_Certificate WITH PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
    set @decryptedText = cast(DECRYPTBYKEY(cast(@encryptedText as nvarchar(max))) as varchar(max))
    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY Encryption_Symmetric_Key
end
```

The procedures seem to work fine when I use the exec command. So far, so good. The problem is that the data is inserted and fetched inside the table using stored procedures; one each for insert and select. What I have as of now is as follows:

**For insertion:**

```
create proc sp_InsertData
@Name nvarchar(100),
@LongText ntext = NULL
as
INSERT INTO TABLE tbl VALUES (@Name, @LongText)
```

**For fetching**

```
create proc sp_FindDataById
@Id int
as
SELECT ID, Name, LongText from tbl where ID=@Id
```

My question is, how do I plug the encryption/decryption procedures inside these SPs to make them work?. I have looked into several articles for achieving this, but I keep running into one issue or another; mostly because of the `ntext` datatype. Or maybe I might be going on the wrong path here. Any kind of help is appreciated.

PS: Due to some reasons specified by the DBAs, I can't change the data type of `LongText` from `ntext` to `nvarchar` or `varchar`. Hence, all the casting is applied in the procedures.

Comment: Slight detour...http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Are your DBAs on drugs? There is zero valid reason for sticking with ntext. That datatype has been deprecated for over a decade in favor of nvarchar(max). But I don't quite understand what the issue is here.

Comment: How will ypou protect the encryption key? What kind of attack are you defending against?

Comment: @SeanLange I have been wondering the same thing. I asked and the response I got was something to do with other procedures and objects getting affected due to changing the data type. I am not sure how true that is, but it is what I am stuck with. The issue here is that I want to create a simple procedure/s to encrypt/decrypt ntext while inserting/fetching rows respectively. The code I provided is what I have till now.

Comment: @zaph The data isn't really that sensitive. Besides, the problem isn't exactly with encryption per se, but with how to modularize the encryption mechanism for reuse across the database. In this scenario I am trying to reuse it for inserting and fetching records.

Comment: I wish you luck with that argument. Sounds like they don't understand the differences of the datatypes or how things can convert across them. I have done many conversions from ntext to nvarchar and never had any issues with it. But that is for another day.

Comment: I would first suggest making the inbound parameter be nvarchar(max) instead of text. Force the conversion outside of this since the ntext datatype is pain to work with. As for doing this kind of thing inline you will almost have to create either a scalar function or a multi-statement table valued function. Neither approach is going to scale very well.

Comment: Did you alter you insert SP as below? What is the exact error you are getting which inserting the data using this SP?  (Sorry unable to format this as code - replace $ by @)       alter proc sp_InsertData
$Name nvarchar(100),
$LongText ntext = NULL
as
declare $encryptedText nvarchar(max)
exec sp_Encrypt_LongText $LongText,$encryptedText
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ($Name, $encryptedText)

Comment: Thank You for all the help guys. Posted the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I managed to convince the DBAs to have the data transferred to a new column with varbinary(max) data type. Then I transferred the values into this new column after encrypting them, and then dropped the older column and renamed the new one to the old one's name. Took some work, but everything is running smoothly now. I managed to create a stored procedure and two functions to further modularize the scripts.

**For opening the symmetric key**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_OpenEncryptionKeys  
AS  
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
  
    BEGIN TRY  
        OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY Encryption_Symmetric_Key  
        DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Encryption_Certificate 
    END TRY  
    BEGIN CATCH  
        --catch
    END CATCH  
END
```

**For encrypting:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION Encrypt
(  
    @ValueToEncrypt varchar(max)  
)  
RETURNS varbinary(max)  
AS  
BEGIN  
    -- Declare the return variable here  
    DECLARE @Result varbinary(max);  
    SET @Result = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('My_Encryption_Symmetric_Key'), @ValueToEncrypt);  
    -- Return the result of the function  
    RETURN @Result  
END
```

**For decrypting:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION Decrypt
(  
    @ValueToDecrypt varbinary(max);  
)  
RETURNS varchar(max)  
AS  
BEGIN  
    -- Declare the return variable here  
    DECLARE @Result varchar(max);  
    SET @Result = DecryptByKey(@ValueToDecrypt);  
    -- Return the result of the function  
    RETURN @Result  
END
```

**For inserting**

```
exec sp_OpenEncryptionKeys  
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ('Name', Encrypt('some text here'));
```

**For fetching**

```
exec sp_OpenEncryptionKeys  
SELECT ID, Decrypt(LongText) from tbl;
```

Hope this helps someone.