# SQL Server decryption options

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, encryption, aes

I have a DB of sales with personal data encrypted with AES. Now I have to create a procedure to find the sale id (a unique code) by the encrypted data such as telephone or email.

The encryption process is made in the web, and uses the unique sale id as password, so the same email with two different sales will be in two different encryption results, because of the different keys used, stored as plain text (varchar).

I have read some Stack Overflow posts, some of the first ones:

- [Create a Stored Procedure for AES Encryption in MS SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42841132/create-a-stored-procedure-for-aes-encryption-in-ms-sql-server-2008)
- [AES Encryption SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45821315/aes-encryption-sql-server)

and the Microsoft site official explanation, but all refers to methods of create a certificate and a key, but I'm looking if it´s possible to use something similar to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/decryptbypassphrase-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016

which uses varbinary to store the encrypted data, and of course with AES instead of TRIPLE DES.

Also, any reccomendation to read is welcome.

Comment: SQL Server's encryption functions can't decrypt arbitrary data, even if the underlying algorithms matched -- it can only decrypt what it has encrypted itself. You can use CLR functions to write the encryption/decryption in .NET if you *must* do it on the DB end, but that has a learning curve. As an aside, if your DB stores the key alongside the encrypted data then you have no actual security at all (except through obscurity), as a cornerstone of encryption is that these two pieces should always remain separate.

Comment: Hello Jeroen, and thanks for your answer, i know that store the key with the encrypted data is a fail, but it is what i have get to work with, im reviewing the process and the desing to see if there are more options, this method of encryption also have the big problem that to find only 1 record, you have to decript all the records (or, at least the record between two given dates) and then compare it. Thank you againg.